# how does javascript or condition work

Tags: javascript, angularjs, prototypejs

i have written my code something like this

```
  this._users = users || [];
```

just wanted to know what does this mean to `this._users`?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Curious why you've written code that you don't understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This basically is evaluating users to true or false. If it evaluation is true, than return users otherwise, assigns an empty array to this._users .